# TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined when i use my own component as contentComponent in createDrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

I have issue with tests when i use my custom SideMenu component as contentComponent in createDrawerNavigator:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined

```
const SideMenu: React.ComponentType<SideMenuProps> = ({
  user = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' },
  navigation,
}) => {
  const navigateTo = (screen: string) => {
    navigation.navigate(screen)
    navigation.closeDrawer()
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView testID="SideMenu" style={SideMenuStyles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        testID="SideMenuHeader"
        style={SideMenuStyles.header}
        onPress={() => navigateTo(SCREEN_NAMES.APP_PROFILE)}
      >
        <Image source={require('@resource/Img/logo.png')} style={SideMenuStyles.avatar} />
        <Text numberOfLines={1} style={SideMenuStyles.headerText}>
          {`${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <ScrollView>
        <SideMenuItem
          title="Community Calendar"
          imageSource={require('@resource/Img/logo.png')}
          onPress={() => navigateTo(SCREEN_NAMES.APP_CALENDAR)}
        />
        <SideMenuItem
          title="Browse Services"
          imageSource={require('@resource/Img/logo.png')}
          onPress={() => navigateTo(SCREEN_NAMES.APP_SERVICES)}
        />
        <SideMenuItem
          title="Building Essentials"
          imageSource={require('@resource/Img/logo.png')}
          onPress={() => navigateTo(SCREEN_NAMES.APP_ESSENTIALS)}
        />
        <SideMenuItem
          title="Communication Portal"
          imageSource={require('@resource/Img/logo.png')}
          onPress={() => navigateTo(SCREEN_NAMES.APP_PORTAL)}
        />
        <SideMenuItem
          title="Neighborhood Perks"
          imageSource={require('@resource/Img/logo.png')}
          onPress={() => navigateTo(SCREEN_NAMES.APP_PERKS)}
        />
        <SideMenuItem
          title="FAQ"
          imageSource={require('@resource/Img/logo.png')}
          onPress={() => navigateTo(SCREEN_NAMES.APP_FAQ)}
        />
      </ScrollView>
      <BuildingLogo style={SideMenuStyles.buildingLogo} />
      <BrandingFooter />
      <Link onPress={() => navigateTo(SCREEN_NAMES.APP_FEEDBACK)} textStyle={SideMenuStyles.link}>
        Leave feedback
      </Link>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default SideMenu
```

```
import { DrawerItemsProps } from 'react-navigation'

export interface SideMenuProps extends DrawerItemsProps {
  user?: {
    firstName: string
    lastName: string
    avatar?: string
  }
}
```

And then added use it as contentComponent in CreateDrawerNavigator as below

```
import { createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

import AppScreens from '@screen/App'
import { SideMenu } from '@component/index'
import { SCREEN_NAMES } from '../constants'

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ...AppScreens,
  },
  { initialRouteName: SCREEN_NAMES.APP_PROFILE },
)

const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  { AppStackNavigator },
  { contentComponent: SideMenu }
)

export default AppNavigator
```

And after that if i run my tests, i receive that error message

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined



      at Object.get [as SideMenu] (src/Components/index.ts:39:22)
      at Object.SideMenu (src/Navigation/Navigators/app.ts:16:23)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/Navigation/Navigators/root.ts:4:1)
```

Things like changing inlineRequires to false in preprocessor.js didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invalid import usage.

Your Side Menu Declarations Code

```js
export default SideMenu
```

**Usage**

```js
import  SideMenu  from '@component/index'
```

instead

```js
import { SideMenu } from '@component/index' // If your code is to be used like this, `export SideMenu`
```

Comment: Thanks, changed import to import SideMenu from '@component/SideMenu' and works fine.